# Tensorflow - Can One-Hot vector impact model learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

I am sorry in advance for my english expression. It is difficult for me..

I have a neural network with features that are in a np array and just before model traning, my features are stored in a tensor. The shape is (4000, 6) because I have 6 differents features

I add a vocabulary feature. I convert it in one-hot vector and convert it in tensor so the shape of this result is (4000, 243).

Just before the training I concat these two tensors so I have a result tensor with shape (4000, 249).

I am wondering if my learning will be impacted by this (6 features and one other encoded on 243 entries in the tensor).
I am worried about the ponderation that neural network will apply..

Is it a problem or my 6 first features will continue to have a best ponderation compared 243 others entries in the tensor ?

Thanks you very much for your answer and your help.

Comment: So If I understand correctly you have a model, with 7 features, 6 of them are stored as integers/floats and the 7th one is a one hot vector of size 243, and you want to know if this will result in your model being impacted heavily by the feature which is onehot encoded?

Comment: yeah it's that. I am worried that at result the six first features will be somehow "ignored" by the feature wich is onehot encoded... It seems to be the case.. With my test my neural network seems to overfitt.. what is your opinion ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes your worries are correct, having one hot encoding for one of the features while representing the model will be bad, it will tend to prioritize different features, now which features will be prioritized depend on a few criterion.

Case 1: You have normalized other Inputs to lie between 0 and 1, In this case the feature represented as a one hot encoding will tend to dominate the models prediction.

Case 2: You have not normalized other Inputs, this will already have disastrous affect, but it will counter huge effects from the one hot encoded vector.

None of these will be ideal for a machine learning scenario, I will suggest you to remove the one hot encoding of the feature and then normalize the dataset, and only then train your model, this will make sure that all your features impact the learning based on their involvement in predicting the output and not be biased towards any particular feature.

If you have any queries or fail to understand the logic of something, feel free to comment.